# Rewrite_rool объединение 2-х условий

Tags: .htaccess, mod_rewrite, https

Значится, проблема такая:

На проекте, сделанном на CodeIgniter, есть файл .htaccess со следующим содержимым:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond $1 !^(index\.php|img|js|css|robots\.txt)
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php?/$1 [L]
```

И все чудно работало.
Появилась необходимость прописать редирект всего с http на https.
Путем гугления были добавлены 2 строки:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteRule (.*) https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [R,L]
```

Все бы ничего, но теперь при переходе по ссылке site.ru идет переброс на https://site.ru/**index.php?/**

Агалогичным образом site.ru/order превращается в https://site.ru/**index.php?/**order

Как это побороть? Спасибо.

**Обновление**

Надо, чтоб адреса типа site.ru/controller перенаправлялись на site.ru/controller/index.php
Это первое условие (ну, по факту, просто делаем красивые урлы, убирая index.php).

Ну и второе - чтоб все запросы http переадресовывались туда же, но на https.

В общем, надо, чтоб если запрашивался site.ru, в урле было http://site.ru,   а не  http://site.ru.index.php?/

Answer (score 1):

RewriteRule делает именно то, что прописано у вас в htaccess.
Напишите, какие, например, адреса запрашиваются и во что должны преобразовываться.

**Обновление**

Сначала делай переадресацию на https, а уже после того, как переадресовано, делай Rewrite, чтобы убрать index.php

Comment: Обновил вопрос.

Comment: Сначала делай переадресацию на https, а уже после того, как переадресовано, делай Rewrite, чтобы убрать index.php